# How can I make File Manager's Unity icon open the already opened window?

Tags: unity, nautilus, 15.10

The below animation demonstrates the problem. Clicking File Manager's Unity icon opens a new window instead of the already opened window. This is different with any other application where clicking the icon puts back focus to the already opened window of the respective application.

Is there any way to change this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: The behaviour is different on my system; when clicked, it raises the existing window.

Comment: Similar posts on AU mention it is a bug. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Dear @JacobVlijm, it's 15.10.  It seems that it only occurs if the open window is a removable device. Local folders do work well.

Comment: I am afraid it *is* the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1170647, which describes it pretty much...